# Recover a SVN repository from ONLY the db folder?

Tags: svn, recovery

I have a project from a year ago from which I would like to recover source code. The SVN repository of that project has ONLY the db folder; however, the db folder seems to be complete, including all the files from the db/revs folder. I have no backup of this SVN repository, and I have no idea what happened to all the other files which should be there.

Unsurprisingly I am unable to recover the working copy from this repository. I have tried to copy in the essential database structure from a working repository, and I have tried to use svnadmin recover, and I cannot get any data out of it.

Is it possible to retrieve at least the last working copy from the db? I would be okay starting a new SVN from that point.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There really isn't much that you need outside of the db directory.

This is what is outside of the db directory:
README.txt (just an explanation that this is a Subversion repo, doesn't matter)
conf (directory with configuration files, mostly for use when used with svnserve, isn't important for recover the contents of the repo)
format (specifies the format of the subversion repo, this should be a file with nothing more than "5\n" in it and hasn't changed since Subversion 1.4.x)
hooks (directory with hook scripts, not needed to read data out of a repo)
locks (lock files location for really old repositories not used since before 1.3.x)

svnadmin recover isn't really all that helpful in a case like this.  It's largely for BDB based repositories (which you probably aren't using).  It doesn't do much in FSFS repositories.

However you ought to be able to do:

```
svnadmin create new-repo
rm -rf new-repo/db
cp -a old-repo/db new-repo
```

I'd suggest once you do that creating another new repo and dumping and reloading into it:

```
svnadmin create final-repo
svnadmin dump new-repo | svnadmin load final-repo
```

It's possible you have a repo with a version of Subversion before 1.4.x in which case you may have to manipulate the format file a bit.  You can see the history of the format file here (near the top, read the comment before SVN_REPOS__FORMAT_NUMBER):
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_repos/repos.h

And of course as always, when trying to recover something work against a copy and not your only copy.

Comment: Ben, thanks for answering. I might actually be using a Berkeley DB. Following your instructions, when I use svnadmin on my machine, I get this error: "e720002: can't open file 'db\DB_CONFIG': The system cannot find the file specified." However, the layout of the 'db' directory I am trying to restore from definitely has the structure of a fsfs directory: folders for revs, revprops, transactions, etc. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What's the content of your `db/format` file and `db/fs-type` file?  You could try creating a new BDB repo with `svandmin create --fs-type=bdb new-repo` and copying the `DB_CONFIG` file into your repo.  If you have a BDB repo there shouldn't be much if any directories in the `db` folder.  There are however files named revisions and transactions (but there won't be a revprops).  As always using copies for any manipulation of the files you do.

Comment: Ben, I really appreciate your help. Using your commands, I managed to fix the database to the point where I could start to get diffs out of it --- which was when I realized that the database is missing 50% of the revs, which renders the remainder of the repository pretty much useless. Not sure where the rest of the data disappeared to, but I don't have a backup, which means that this is where my inquiry must end. Thanks again for helping; answer accepted.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Sorry to hear that you couldn't recover it.

Comment: This is exactly what was needed. Thank you!

Comment: Just a note - although this strategy did recreate a repo, it was missing a lot of commits. I just created a new repo and copied my old db folder over, and it looks like all of it is there now - so you might try this as another option.

Comment: @VisionHive Copying your db folder into a new repo is the first step.  Unless you did something to the dump I don't think you should end up with missing revisions.  It's been a long time since I answered this but I think I said to do the dump/load cycle to refill some caches that would have been lost but that aren't critical.

Comment: @BenReser I know, I did it both ways. Dump/export the untouched folder with the db copied over into a new repo didn't work - but replacing the db folder in the repo with the archived version afterwards did work.